# Continuous gradient over two seperate divs

Tags: html, css

I have two divs where one of them acts like a section divider.
I would like to make a continuous gradient over both of them.
See expected output in picture. Where the white space in div1 is transparent

I can only manage to get gradient on both, but not continous.

[image: Countiunous]

Comment: can you wrap them in an outer div, then give that outer div the gradient background?

Comment: That's my thought also, or use a script to calculate the terminal color value.

Comment: Unfortunately this will defeat the purpose of having the divider.
Everyhing will be filled with a gradient - yes - but including the transparent part above the shape.

Comment: I don't see how that defeats the purpose. Please revise to describe the overall project better. You're asking an [XY question](http://xyproblem.info/) instead of seeking viable solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? i am not 100% sure i understood you right (shape is just an example thats easier to make)

```css
.parent{
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.parent > div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.top{
clip-path: polygon(13% 73%, 30% 61%, 45% 69%, 66% 60%, 79% 65%, 100% 59%, 100% 85%, 100% 100%, 85% 100%, 15% 100%, 0 100%, 0 78%);
  background: rgb(252,176,69);
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(252,176,69,1) 0%, rgba(194,52,52,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 53%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.bottom{
  background: rgb(65,255,224);
  background: linear-gradient(360deg, rgba(65,255,224,0.48503151260504207) 0%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.outer {
  background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255, 164, 113, 1) 0%, rgba(251, 90, 111, 1) 100%);
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid;
  min-height: 80px; /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">First content</div>
    <div class="inner">Second content</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kt2Lxnce/)